# Help getting Unison to sync

Tags: 16.04, mac, unison

I'm trying to get Unison to sync two folders, one on my Ubuntu computer and one on my Mac. (I was able to get Rsync working earlier, but I want bidirectional syncing, so I'm looking at Unison). As a test, I created a simple folder on my Ubuntu machine named syncTest that contains two text files, file1.txt and file2.txt. Then I used this command:

```
unison ~/syncTest/ ssh://admin@Macbook.local//Users/Admin/syncTest
```

The output of the command is this:

```
Contacting server...Connected [//MacBook.local//Users/Admin/syncTest -
> //notre-ubuntu//home/notre/syncTest]
Looking for changes
Warning: No archive files were found for these roots, whose canonical 
names are:
     /home/notre/syncTest
    //MacBook.local//Users/Admin/syncTest
This can happen either
because this is the first time you have synchronized these roots, 
or because you have upgraded Unison to a new version with a different
archive format.  


 Update detection may take a while on this run if the replicas are 
 large.


 Unison will assume that the 'last synchronized state' of both 
 replicas was completely empty.  This means that any files that are 
 different will be reported as conflicts, and any files that exist 
 only on one replica will be judged as new and propagated to the other 
 replica. If the two replicas are identical, then no changes will be 
 reported.


 If you see this message repeatedly, it may be because one of your 
 machines is getting its address from DHCP, which is causing its host 
 name to change between synchronizations.  See the documentation for 
 the UNISONLOCALHOSTNAME environment variable for advice on how to 
 correct this.


 Donations to the Unison project are gratefully accepted: 
 http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison


 Press return to continue.[<spc>]   Waiting for changes from server
 Reconciling changes


 local          MacBook.l...       
 dir      ---->            /  [f]
```

At this point, nothing further happens. It appears to be sitting indefinitely on my Ubuntu computer. Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to press the <kbd>f</kbd>-key. Unison is waiting for you to confirm to proceed with the synchronization. The arrow means that it will sync from `local` to `MacBook.l`.

Comment: Ok, badly formulated answer. I'll edit it to be more clear.

Comment: Ok, I feel like an idiot. Thanks Melebius, that worked!